# getting method address in JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Once you've done:

```
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "run", "()V");
```

how do you get the run address so that you can pass the function pointer as an argument to a C function? Perhaps some `jmethodID` field? I haven't been able to find it in the jni docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You must use the CallXXXMethod() family of APIs. That's what they're for. If you can't disturb the code that wants a function pointer, you will have to write the callback yourself in C and have it call CallXXXMethod() itself, saving the jobject and methodID somehow.

Comment: Imagine you want to interface to a signal-like C-library where the signal handler is a Java method. Somewhere you'll have to write in the JNI side `signal(SIGALRM, function_pointer)`. Obviously you don't want to rewrite signal function. If you cannot do that I see that as a big JNI limitation

Comment: Adding to my last comment... It seems that a `(*env)->GetAddress(env, mid)` is lacking

Comment: ok @EJP, now I understand what you mean, program a C wrapper function which would invoke `CallXXXMethod` and would be passed as a callback (instead of a Java method address, which anyway cannot be done). It Seems a great workaround, thanks

Comment: @francesc Of course it's 'missing.' It's not meant to be there. C code cannot call Java code directly. That's what `CallXXXMethod()` is *for.* That's *why* methods are returned as `methodIDs,` not as function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Your populated method in C/C++ will look like:

```
#include "MyTest.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
 Java_InstanceMethodCall_nativeMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
 {
     jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
     jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "run", "()V");
     (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, mid);
 }
```

The signature is generated using javah.